# Confusion in symbols of a book

Tags: discrete-mathematics, notation

I was reading book "" Concrete Mathematics by

Ronald L. Graham
AT&T Bell Laboratories,
]
Donald E. Knuth
Stanford University,
Oren Patashnik
Center for Communications Research""

and I cam across these statements

[m/n]    1 if m divides n, otherwise 0    ,,,,,,                  and 
[m//n]   1 if m exactly divides n, otherwise 0

Please explain the difference between the two since both explain the same thing if n divides completely m then equal to 1 else 0..

Comment: does he give examples?

Comment: The definition of "exactly divides" is on page 146, Ex. 25.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’ve miscopied the notation. They write $m\backslash n$ to mean that there is an integer $k$ such that $n=mk$; this is their version of the more usual notation $m\mid n$, read ‘$m$ divides $n$’. They write $m\backslash\backslash n$ to mean that there is an integer $k$ such that $n=km$ **and** $\gcd(k,m)=1$: $m$ divides $n$, and $m$ and $\frac{n}m$ are relatively prime.

Answer (score 0):

I am acquainted with $a\mid b$ for $\exists c\colon b=ac$ and, if $a$ is a prime, $a^n\|b$ for $a^n\mid b\land a^{n+1}\nmid b$. A generalization of $\|$ to arbitrary integers would be to define $a\|b$ as $a|b\land \gcd(a,\tfrac ba)=1$.